# In app billing v3 sample application

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement in app billing in my application by following the training section on developer.android.com [here](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html) But I can't find the `TrivialDrive` sample from eclipse to import under samples and even though I see it in my sdk I can't get it to import. Any help would be great.

[This is a screenshot](http://postimage.org/image/stryq0mq9/) of what happens when i try to import into eclipse manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have installed the Google Play Billing Library through the Android SDK Manager, if you click File -> New -> Other -> Android Project from Existing Code -> Navigate to your SDK folder -> extras -> google -> play_billing -> select in-app-billing-v03 and click ok and then finish.

Just tried it myself, and that works perfectly! If you're still having problems, please do tell

Comment: That generally means it's already imported; I also assume the checkbox underneath it greyed out. Look for MainActivity in your project list, it should be there.

Comment: Ah, I do already have a project named MainActivity in my project list but It is a different project I can't remove, any idea on what I should do?

Comment: Make sure you do *NOT* have another project named "MainActivity" in eclipse. You need to rename the old "MainActivity" first before trying to import this sample project again.

Comment: Got it, I just renaimed MainActivity, Thanks so much both of you

Comment: am i the only one who can`t see the folder in-app-billing-v03 ? i already downloaded the Google Play Billing Library, but it only brings the TrivialDrive v2 project. am i missing something ?